# Deploy to Azure Web App runs successfully on GitHub Actions but still ModuleNotFoundError on Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, github-actions, azure-webapps

We deploy to our Web App using GitHub Actions and Azure Web App template provided [here](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/python-webapp-on-azure.yml).

Everything runs successfully on GitHub Actions and the deploy as well, but we still get an error on our Web App looking at the logs.

Our deploy YAML:

```yaml
name: My App
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: my-app
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.8' # supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)
jobs:
  build-and-deploy-to-Azure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
    - name: 'Install dependencies'
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}@github".insteadOf https://github
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

Last few lines of step `Install dependencies`:

```
Successfully installed Faker-6.1.1 Flask-1.1.2 Flask-Bcrypt-0.7.1 Flask-Bootstrap-3.3.7.1 Flask-Cors-3.0.10 Flask-Dropzone-1.5.4 Flask-Login-0.5.0 Flask-Mail-0.9.1 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.4.4 Flask-WTF-0.14.3 Jinja2-2.11.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.23 Six-1.15.0 WTForms-2.3.3 Werkzeug-1.0.1 bcrypt-3.2.0 blinker-1.4 cffi-1.14.5 click-7.1.2 dnspython-2.1.0 dominate-2.6.0 email-validator-1.1.2 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 idna-3.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jdcal-1.4.1 numpy-1.20.1 openpyxl-3.0.6 pandas-1.2.2 pycparser-2.20 pyodbc-4.0.30 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-dotenv-0.15.0 pytz-2021.1 steekproef-0.0.1 text-unidecode-1.3 visitor-0.1.3 xlrd-2.0.1 xlsxwriter-1.3.7
```

Then lastly, the error on our app:

```
2021-02-15T16:51:47.899495269Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 1, in <module>
2021-02-15T16:51:47.899499469Z     from my_app import app
2021-02-15T16:51:47.899503270Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/my_app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-02-15T16:51:47.899507570Z     from flask_login import LoginManager
2021-02-15T16:51:47.899511570Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

What am I missing here that every step in my deployment goes correctly, while still the app cannot find the dependencies which are installed during deployment?

Comment: If flask_login is installed manually via ssh, will the webapp program return to normal?

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: Didn't have time to try it yet, will do asap. What do you exactly mean with concerns in this case?

Comment: Want to know if you solved this problem? You can install flask_login manually to try. If the program can return to normal, you can find other methods. When the program is updated and deployed, execute this command to solve the problem.

Comment: Can't connect with SSH, I have the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/45235/app-service-ssh-connection-issue.html) problem

Comment: I am in contact met microsoft, will send an update here.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am facing the same issue.